# HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'CustomUser.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'

Tags: python, django, django-models, abstractuser

I need help. I'm creating an app in Django and I'm having some trouble making migrations of my custom user's class. The error is:

```
ERRORS: auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Usuario.groups'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'Usuario.groups'. auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Usuario.user_permissions'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'Usuario.user_permissions'. usuarios.Usuario.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Usuario.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Usuario.groups' or 'User.groups'. usuarios.Usuario.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Usuario.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Usuario.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
```

Now, this is my code:

My Model:

```py
from django.db import models from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser from django.conf import settings

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=80)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['USERNAME']

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

class Perfil(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, related_name="usuario_user" , on_delete=models.CASCADE)                             
    nacionality= models.ForeignKey(Paises, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)    
    rol= models.ForeignKey(Rol, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING) def str(self): return self.CustomUser
    birth_date=models.DateField()
```

In my `settings.py`:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODELS= 'users.CustomUser'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL= reverse_lazy('home')
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL= reverse_lazy('login')
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login')

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.users',
]
```

Comment: In settings.py try using AUTH_USER_MODEL instead of AUTH_USER_MODELS

Comment: thanks,  it's working.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

You can change the base model you inherited so instead of **AbstractUser**, just use **User** like:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CustomUser(User):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=80)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['USERNAME']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

take this reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

it will now works better. Thanks alot for question.

and in the **settings.py** add correctly this line:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'name_of_app.NameOfModel'
```

Comment: The main point here is setting up `AUTH_USER_MODEL` correctly not changing `AbstractUser` to `User`.

Answer (score 0):

In **"settings.py"**, use **"AUTH_USER_MODEL"** instead of **"AUTH_USER_MODELS"** as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

In addition, even if you assign a tuple or list to **"AUTH_USER_MODELS"** as shown below, you will get the same error:

```py
# "settings.py"

AUTH_USER_MODELS = ('users.CustomUser',) # Get the same error
```

Or:

```py
# "settings.py"

AUTH_USER_MODELS = ['users.CustomUser',] # Get the same error
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, try this.    `\\\  groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='customuser_set', blank=True) user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name='customuser_set', blank=True)` \\

```
[enter code here][1]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).